# Bitwise operations

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, bit-manipulation

A) `(Int32)X | ((Int32)Y << 16)`;

B) `(Int32)X + (Int32)Y * (Int32)Int16.MaxValue`;

Shouldn't both be equivalent? I know from testing that the first works as expected, but for some reason the second doesn't. Both X and Y are shorts (`Int16`), and the return type is an integer (`Int32`).

Shouldn't `Y << 16` <=> `Y * Int16.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour, you need to multiply with `0x10000` (i.e. `UInt16.MaxValue+1`). `Int16.MaxValue` is `0x7fff`.

```
5 << 16
327680

5 * 0x10000
327680
```

Compare to the decimal system: If you want to "shift" the number 5 to 500, you need to multiply with 100, not 99 :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your second approach:

- Int16 is signed, so the max value is actually only 15 bits.
- The maximum value that can be represented by 16 bits is 2^16 - 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Right-shift 16 bits = * 2^16
```

But:

```
Int16.MaxValue = 2^15-1
```

I think that you want an unsigned 16-bit max value + 1

Comment: Unsigned 16-bit max value is still 2^16-1.

Answer (score 1):

Overlooking your MaxValue being one less than a power of two, and since you have a bigger problem to cover first:

The **OR** and **SUM** operations are not similar. When you are working with 32-bit integers and 16-bit shifts, there will be **carries** with your **`+`** operation and **bit-wise OR'ing** with the **OR** operation.

So, the two ways are quite different.

Then, of course, the MaxValue interpretation makes your two 'shift' attempts different. It should be `(x * MaxValue + x)` or `(x * (MaxValue+1))`.

Comment: Since the original values are 16-bit there won't be any carry/overflow.

Comment: Ah! I seem to have overlooked the int16 reference. Then it is also likely that the compiler will use **OR** anyways.